# In a civil case against the US gov't, complaint was not contested by defendant; can the judge reject a request of the plaintiff without a hearing?

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure, us-federal-government, jury, federal-courts

There is a (valid) civil lawsuit which was filed against the US government, its agencies and officers at a district federal court. The plaintiff did not ask for a jury.

The US government (through the US attorney) has not responded during the response period.

Now the response period has expired, but it's unknown if the defendants (government and its agencies) were formally declared in default by the court, because...

...immediately after the deadline for the defendants to respond has expired, the case was decided by the judge without a hearing, and the case was closed.

In such a scenario, is it legal for the judge to decide against the requests of the plaintiff as they appeared in the complaint? These requests ask to do legal actions.

For example, is it legal for the judge to reject the following requests?

1. The plaintiff requested to declare that the sued US agency had acted unlawfully.
2. The plaintiff requested that the judge would order the sued US agency to stop acting unlawfully.
3. The plaintiff requested that the judge would order the sued US agency to resolve a matter within 10 days, but the judge order the agency to resolve it only within 3 months.

Would the judge have been allowed to decide the case without a hearing if the plaintiff had asked to have a jury (and the defendants have not responded)?

Would the judge have been allowed to reject a request made by plaintiff in the complaint, if the plaintiff had asked to have a jury and the jury agreed to the request of the plaintiff (and the defendants have not responded)?

Comment: What was the nature of the lawsuit? What was the stated basis for the ruling? Was service of process effected and duly filed?

Comment: Why did the judge say it was dismissed?

Comment: I never said the case was dismissed. It was decided by the judge without a hearing, and the case was closed. This is "legal" in the US civil law, at least when both parties respond, but correct me if I am wrong. I don't know how it can coexist with due process. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_due_process

Comment: It is unusual which is why I'm trying to figure out better what the basis of the lawsuit was if it was closed. If it was a matter of subject-matter jurisdiction, for example, a judge can rule *sua sponte* without another party participating. There are some other rare exceptions. Trying to determine what might apply.

Comment: What is unusual? The case was decided by the judge (without a hearing though, which I assume is legal in a civil case), that's why it was then closed. When a case is decided and there is a "judgment", then normally the case is closed. Correct me if I am wrong (my knowledge of the formal law is elementary).

Comment: It is unusual for a case to be decided without the other party appearing other than by a default judgment especially when the U.S. government is a party.

Comment: Without tying any specific case to OP, since questions have to be general, I can suggest merely as an EXAMPLE, that such a case may be a lawsuit against USCIS et al. for violation of 8 U.S.C. § 1447(b). Complaint may request: judge declares FBI "name check" is illegal, judge declares CARRP is illegal, judge adjudicates naturalization application or remands application to USCIS with an order to adjudicate application within 10 days.

Comment: That's helpful.

Comment: I actually thought (and "heard" from people in legal/attorney circles, who of course, rely on their professional experience) that it's rare (or rather zero-probability) that a US attorney would fail to respond to a lawsuit against the government. So I was taken by surprise. Then I thought, did the US attorney collude with the judge to "get rid" of the lawsuit? It's admittedly a powerful tactic (though dishonest and underhanded, not what I would expect from the "staunch defenders of justice"), why is it not used more often?

Comment: Quite possibly. Default judgments don't create precedents or bind the U.S. in future cases and often if a case is clear loser it will be left to default strategically to avoid an impact on future cases.

Comment: It's strange, because from what I have "heard", USCIS (through US attorney) usually tries to negotiate with the plaintiff, in order to come to agreement and mutually dismiss the case. But in this hypothetical case, USCIS kept silent. They could have tried to negotiate it informally, and if it fails, still not respond to the court. Could be, USCIS wanted to have the case remanded to them without making any guarantees on approving the application. Is it a new underhanded tactic to circumvent the law? And would asking for a jury trial prevent the judge from closing the case without a hearing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129962/discussion-between-rapt-and-ohwilleke).